# NoMethodError using Prawn and Rails Casts as reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, prawn

I`m using Prawn 0.14.0

I'm using the rails casts #153 Pdf With Prawn Revised as reference to generate a pdf with some informations and a table.But I`m getting this error:

NoMethodError in LendingsController#show - undefined method `line_items'

I can generate the pdf and some information appears if I don`t call the method "line_item_rows" inside the "line_items method"But if I try to populate the table calling line_item_rows,I get the error above.

I have this in my TermPdf class:

```
class TermPdf < Prawn::Document

def initialize(lending)
    super() 
    @lending_term = lending
    line_items
end


def line_items
    move_down 20
    table line_item_rows       
end  

def line_item_rows
  [["Equipament","Brand","Tipping","Description"]] + 
    @lending_term.line_items.map do |item|
       [
         item.equipment.title,
         item.equipment.brand.title,
         item.equipment.tipping,
         item.description
       ]
    end  
end
```

end

and this is the show method in LendingsController

```
def show
   @lending = Lending.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
         format.pdf do        
           pdf = TermPdf.new(@lending)
           send_data pdf.render, filename: "Agreement Number #{@lending.id}.pdf",
                          type: "application/pdf",
                          disposition: 'inline' 
       end  
      format.json { render json: @lending }
    end
end
```

I really tried to fix this error but no success.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to come from here:

```
@lending_term.line_items
```

Now i don't know if this is a relation or a class method but you need to check it out!! PDF code seems clean to me.

A little advise here is to avoid ambiguous naming in your code. You were looking at the wrong direction because you used the name "Line_items" in different cases which made debugging harder.